# CruiseControl.rb always running my projects in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.rb

I'm curious as to why when I build my project using CruiseControl.rb, it runs it in production mode? Even though my application should not be in production mode. I even tried to specify: `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'` in my app's environment.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That environment.rb line will only set your environment to development if the environment is not already set.

For information about how they suggest configuring your build environments, see:

[Their Manual Entry on the subject](http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/documentation/manual#changing_the_build_command)